# Plotly Js Choropleth Iso2 instead of Iso3

Tags: javascript, arrays, plotly, iso, choropleth

I have data which has the country code as ISO2 and choropleth required ISO3 for display locations. 
Is there any other way to use ISO2 instead of ISO3 ??

Answer (score 3):

Used mapping of ISO2 for ISO3

check out this:

http://country.io/iso3.json